# How can I set user_id in OAuth 2.0 PHP Server?

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, token, userid

I'm using [bshaffer OAuth 2.0 PHP Server](https://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/). 
I want to create a token with user_id. 
How can I achive this?

I don't know if I have to make it after the handleTokenRequest() or before? 
Within one response or in a separate api request?

My token provider:

```
    $userid = 1234;
    $request = OAuth2\Request::createFromGlobals();
    $response = new OAuth2\Response();
    $OAuth2Server->handleAuthorizeRequest($request, $response, true, $userid);
    $OAuth2Server->handleTokenRequest($request, $response);
    $response->send();
```

What am I missing to store the userid to the oauth_access_tokens table?